# Python private class fields, how to make?

Tags: python

I'm beginner. In Delphi I can make private field in class: moving it to `private` section. So `ClassVar.Field` doesn't exist out of class.

In Python, if I make class

```
class CName:
  testname = 10
```

then `testname` can be accessed always. How can I make a field "private"?

Comment: There are no private variables in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't!

Naming fields with two underscores will hide it (generate a new name) but you will always be able to access it. Try `__testname = 10`